# Expectation of a linear combinations of iid standard normal, restricted to a halfspace

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution, expectation

Let $u = (u_1, \ldots, u_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $Y_i$ be i.i.d standard normal

Is there any easy way to calculate

$$\mathbb{E} \left[  1_{\displaystyle \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n u_i \cdot Y_i  > 0 \right\}}   \sum_{i=1}^n u_i \cdot Y_i  \right] $$

---

**Progress**: for $n=1$, it is an easy calculation. For $n \geq 2$, it seems to be messy.  In fact, I think this is equal to $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$. I need this result to prove that the random line segment $L = (0, \sqrt{2\pi} Y)$ has the expectation = the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $Y$ is a standard gaussian in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Cool question. I wanna know too.

Comment: Where is your problem here?

Comment: @Karl i have no idea how to begin with. there may be some trick to make it easy.

Comment: @Karl for $n=1$, it is an easy calculation. For $n \geq 2$, it seems to be messy.  In fact, I think this is equal to $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$. I need this result to prove that the random line segment $L = (0, \sqrt{2\pi} Y)$ has the expectation = the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $Y$ is a standard gaussian in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Note that $\sum\limits_iu_iY_i$ is normal centered with variance $\sum\limits_iu_i^2=1$ hence one is asking for $E(Z:Z>0)$ where $Z$ is standard normal. Can you compute *that*?

Comment: @Did, thanks! I am now shocked by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Did is spot on. I'll just show you the details:

We can reformulate the expression within the square brackets as follows:

\begin{align*}
1_{\displaystyle \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n u_i \cdot Y_i  > 0 \right\}}   \sum_{i=1}^n u_i \cdot Y_i  = \max\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i \cdot Y_i,  0 \right)
\end{align*}

We then have $\sum_{i=1}^n u_i \cdot Y_i \sim N(0, 1)$ by iid and the fact that $u$ is a unit vector. So, we are basically finding the expected value of the [folded-normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution) with $\mu = 0, \sigma^2 = 1$, and so the expected value is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

Comment: My bad, Did, it's corrected now.